# A password consists of 28 characters, each character being a lowercase letter. A password must contain exactly one vowel.How many passwords are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have forgotten a lot of the counting portion of my discrete structures course and need some explanations how to count, maybe some general strategies on counting.

Some example questions I need explaining are

A password consists of 28 characters, each character being a lowercase letter. A password must contain exactly one vowel. How many passwords are there?

a) $5\cdot21^{27}$

b) $28\cdot5\cdot21^{27}$

c) $28\cdot5\cdot27^{21}$

d) $28\cdot5\cdot26^{27}$

if anyone can help explain these questions to me that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

We start by choosing the position for the vowel, which gives us $\binom{28}{1} = 28$ options. We then choose a vowel: $\binom{5}{1} = 5$. These selections are independent; so by rule of product, we multiply to get: $28 * 5$.

Finally, we consider $21$ characters for a space, times each of the remaining $27$ spaces. This is a word, so we have $21^{27}$ remaining possibilities. Again, we multiply by rule of product to get a final answer of: $28 * 5 * 21^{27}$.

**Edit**: I edited because I overlooked the "exactly one vowel" constraint.

Comment: Wouldn't this be overcounting since there is only 1 vowel and not multiple ones?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for catching that! I missed that in the problem statement, but edited to fix. :-)

Comment: Ok, much better now.